# Как в tkinter включать программу сразу развернутой (maximize)

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, tkinter, окно

Я разрабатываю *игру*, и мне бы хотелось, чтобы окно игры сразу открывалось **большим**, **развернутым**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам подойдёт окно на весь экран (перекрывает панель Windows):

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.overrideredirect(1)
window.state('zoomed')
```

Если нужно оставить панель Windows и верхнюю полосу приложения:

```
from tkinter import *
window =Tk()
window.state('zoomed')
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня window.state('zoomed') вызывает ошибку (я под Linux), а этот способ работает:

```
root = tk.Tk()
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)  # На весь экран (Fullscreen)
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)      # Развернуть (Maximize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы было в фулскрин на всех платформах(linux, mac, windows)
нужно использовать параметр -fullscreen  в атрибутах окна. Вот так:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
'''как раз тут мы и используем 
атрибуты окна и пишем фулскрин''' 
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```

Так как мы не добавили кнопку выхода, мы не сможем выйти:( НО можем нажать alt + f4 и закрыть окно или нажать   win + d и закрыть компилятор.